# How to create mobile ready layouts in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin

How do I go about creating a layout or page with `vaadin` that works on both mobile and desktop screens? When I put things side by side, I can't override the styling to make them appear above or below one another no matter how specific I make the CSS.

```
HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
layout.addComponents(new Label("Test"), new Label("Test"));
layout.addStyleName("my-layout");
```

Answer (score 0):

HorizontalLayout is not meant for responsive layouts. If you want to create responsive layouts and use CSS use `Div` instead. There's an example here https://vaadin.com/tutorials/vaadin-key-concepts